# Two fight, the third benefits

Tags: idiom-requests

What is a classic saying for a third party getting all the benefit while two others are fighting.

For example (from wikipedia):
Two dogs fight for a bone, but a third one runs away with it.

Comment: This is reminiscent of the situation where Nash in 'A Beautiful Mind' suggests a cooperative aiming for the second (sentient) prize(s). But only one bone here, and hard to belittle. // There _should_ be a proverb, say, covering the very feasible (and doubtless common) situation you describe. There **must** be.

Comment: The metaphor as you state it is actually used, though the wording is not fixed. "If there was any doubt after last week's head-to-head between Clegg and Farage over who is winning the EU in/out debate, there can be absolutely no doubt this morning. But now we see the third dog entering the fray quietly hoping to run off with the bone in the form of David Cameron on the BBC this morning." [[Jeff Taylor_The Economic Voice_Apr 3, 2014](https://www.economicvoice.com/nigel-farage-is-winning-the-war-of-hearts-and-minds-over-eu-membership/)].

Comment: Andre Norton, in ['Scarface'](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6r-mAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT49&lpg=PT49&dq=%22when+the+lions+fight,+then+do+the+wolves+dine+well%22&source=bl&ots=VLIGXKiMnD&sig=ACfU3U3EHJvAaQC0bmZ3-xCb4RckMdqsuw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ9PWSwpnlAhWPa8AKHWwfBg4Q6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22when%20the%20lions%20fight%2C%20then%20do%20the%20wolves%20dine%20well%22&f=false), seems to have coined **When the lions fight, then do the wolves dine well** with this meaning (a third party seizing an opportunity while the big boys are fighting). But it doesn't seem to have caught on yet.

Comment: Do not put “please help” in titles. That is a request with no place in a title and will antagonize other users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any English word/phrase for waiting for two enemies to destroy/weaken each other?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471432/any-english-word-phrase-for-waiting-for-two-enemies-to-destroy-weaken-each-other)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Oxford Dictionary of **Proverbs**][1], the moral is embodied in the story of the lion, the bear, and the fox, which is included in many post-medieval editions of *Aesop's Fables*.

Early reference:
c 1386 Chaucer / Knight's Tale: "We strive as wide the hounds for the boon.... There cam a kyte, while that they were so wrothe, And baar awey the boon betwixe hem bothe.

Further references in 1534, 1639, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that the third party is an **opportunist**.

From Oxford:

> noun…
>   a person who exploits circumstances to gain immediate advantage rather than being guided by consistent principles or plans.
>   "Most burglaries are committed by casual opportunists"